# Laravel Authorization for Eloquent collection

Tags: laravel-5.1

How to apply laravel Gate (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization) for an eloquent collection.

It works for single item like below

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);

if ($user->cannot('view-post', $post)) {
   abort(403);
}
```

But not working for a collection. Is it possible to filter the collection using Gate and return a collection?

```
$posts = Post::all();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question. Maybe some like this:

```
$post->filter(function($value,$key){
  if(\Gate::allows('view-post',$value)){
    return $val;
  }
});
```

but there must be a better solution.

Related links: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-filter 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization